# Use of indexing JSON response by Google and other search engines?

Tags: ajax, json

Usually JSON responses for AJAX are not full stories. But succinct structured response to specific queries. Does google index them? How important I submit those AJAX URLs to Google? Because the google crawler will get only the JSON string - not the whole context? Am I missing few things?

Comment: I don't think google will index your json at all.

Comment: Thanks bhspencer! In, https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started In this google page, I assume "make your AJAX application crawlable" means that it is generic for any AJAX call. Is it so? If Google is not indexing why it should crawl?

Comment: The page you like to describes a way of mapping urls that point at client side dynamically generated content to static snapshots of that html content that google can index. Google will only index static content. You would need to create static snapshots of your dynamic content and host those static snapshots on your site for indexing.

Comment: "Your part of the agreement is to provide the crawler with an HTML snapshot of this URL"

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification on HTML snapshot. Right now I am receiving a JSON from server to update a region in the HTML. The HTML snapshot is composed in client side by Javascript by parsing the JSON. Looks like I should use one of techniques mentioned in https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot to make the HTML snapshot crawlable.